# Ansible - define variable inside groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Folks,

I'm trying to achieve the below by using the groups parameter in Ansible.

`{{ groups['kafka'] | map('extract',hostvars,'ansible_host') | list | join(':{{ zookeeper_port }},') + ':{{ zookeeper_port }}' }}`

variable zookeeper_port is given as:

```
zookeeper_port: 2181
```

While running my playbook with the above parameter for groups included, it gives me the result as:

```
IP:{{ zookeeper_port }},IP:{{ zookeeper_port }}
```

instead I'm trying to get the result as :

```
IP:2181,IP:2181
```

Can anyone help me figuring out what went wrong at my groups parameter declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything inside `''` inside `{{}}` treated as literal string. To access variables you type them right away - without any surrounding characters. In your case you need something like:

```
{{ groups['kafka'] | map('extract',hostvars,'ansible_host') | list | join(':' + zookeeper_port|string + ',') + ':' + zookeeper_port|string }}"
```

Notice the `string` filter - if your zookeeper_port defined as integer, then without it the task will fail

Comment: Any idea on how I can define it as Int instead of string?

Comment: @AkhilS, define what? In my example defining zookeeper_port should work either way (with or without quote marks)